# public ip amazon ec2 request timed out

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an Amazon ec2 instance, and I see a public DNS and a public ip. However if I try to ping the public ip I receive a "Request timed out".

How can I reach my server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AWS blocks all ICMP requests, which includes pings, by default. You'd have to open up ICMP traffic in the instance's security groups.